# The "You must have 50 reputation to comment" notification is not very readable

Tags: bug, design, css

I just realized that this sites color scheme makes it nearly impossible to see how much rep you need to add a comment. Change it, maybe, possibly? Here's a screenshot.

[image]

EDIT: I'm using Chrome version 45.0.2454.101 on Windows 10

Comment: Good point. It doesn't happen to me though. Maybe your browser.

Comment: more information. Which browser/version/OS for starters.

Comment: I'm using Chrome version 45.0.2454.101 on Windows 10